# Css3 Radial Gradient alternative for IE older versions

Tags: css

when it comes to gradients we have lots of options to choose from:
1- Css3
2- SVG
3- Image
there could be more options but these are the most common. If the gradient is a linear one then it degrades gracefully in IE older version but here what I am talking about is a Radial gradient made with css3.
here is the css for it:

```
background: #7d7e7d;
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #7d7e7d 0%, #0e0e0e 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,#7d7e7d), color-stop(100%,#0e0e0e));
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #7d7e7d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%);
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #7d7e7d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%);
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #7d7e7d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%);
background: radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #7d7e7d 0%,#0e0e0e 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7d7e7d', endColorstr='#0e0e0e',GradientType=1 );
```

for a live demo you can see this page http://bloghutsbeta.blogspot.com/

Now I am asking for a solution for this issue as if you see that demo page in IE then you can see that the way radial gradient is displayed is not good. If I use an Image that would be too big in size, I can't afford image bigger than 5KB. If I use SVG then we all know about its support in browsers.
A good advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Image as I don't see another option available for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider targeting IE only and using SVG, which [this tool can generate](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/SVGGradientBackgroundMaker/Default.html). If you need to support "older" versions (as your title indicates), then some libraries may be needed as [this article talks about](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/using-svg-for-flexible-scalable-and-fun-backgrounds-part-i/).